# How to resolve ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'srsly.msgpack.util' in PyInstaller?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, msgpack

I am trying to convert a python script to .exe using PyInstaller. 
The script is converted to an exe without any error logs.

However while running the .exe file am getting **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'srsly.msgpack.util'**

The issue is occurring while opening the exe files generated both by PyInstaller and cx_Freeze. 
[The Screenshot of the error is attached here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NS9jG.png)

Have tried updating, un-install and re-installing of packages, but still the issue persists.

**Versions:**

- Python : 3.7
- OS : Windows 10
- cx_Freeze : 6.0
- msgpack : 0.6.2
- PyInstaller : 3.5
- srsly : 0.1.0

Comment: Hi, were you able to overcome this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When PyInstaller evaluated your script, it did not predict the dependency on srsly.msgpack.util.  You can manually specify dependencies using `--hiddenimport`.

```
    pyinstaller --hiddenimport srsly.msgpack.util your_script.py
```

You may find that fixing this problem just reveals another.  You can add as many `--hiddenimport` hints as you need.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is mentioned here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/msgpack/0.5.1

When upgrading from msgpack-0.4 or earlier, don’t do pip install -U msgpack-python. Do pip uninstall msgpack-python; pip install msgpack instead.

Comment: I had tried this as well, but couldn't resolve the issue.  
pip uninstall msgpack-python gives 'WARNING: Skipping msgpack-python as it is not installed.' ---------  Thanks